# Если ширина окна больше (показывать jivosite)

Tags: if, width

Салют! Хочу чтобы онлайн-консультант  jivosite не показывался при ширине монитора менее 770px.

CSS не помогает:

```
@media (max-width: 770px) {
    #jivo_top_wrap, #jivo_chat_widget, 
    #jivo-label-wrapper, div#jivo_chat_widget, 
    #tel, #jivo, #jivo-iframe-container, #zub p {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

JQUERY не подходит - так как не хочу подключать не нужную мне библиотеку.

```
if( $(window).width() > 770) {
    код 
}
```

Какие могут быть ещё варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно подправить сам скрипт чата, раньше я добавлял в начало скрипта:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 580) {
```

Или написать в ТП Jivosite, они по запросу делают индивидуальные css стили для виджета и логику поведения.

Answer (score 0):

Css должен помочь, может быть вы не правильно указываете селектор или условие?
Попробуйте также

```
display: none !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь: [Измерения окна, документа и элементов](http://javascript.ru/blog/andrej-paranichev/izmereniya-okna-dokumenta-elementov)

> Для получения размеров окна браузера целиком во всех браузерах, кроме
>   Internet Explorer, вы можете использовать свойства window.outerWidth и
>   window.outerHeight.